# SassError: $color: null is not a color

Tags: angular, sass, kendo-ui

I am using angular v13. I am importing kendo-theme-bootstrap and I am getting following error:

```
SassError: $color: null is not a color.
╷
```

185 │     "r": red($color),
│          ^^^^^^^^^^^
╵
node_modules/@progress/kendo-theme-bootstrap/modules/bootstrap/scss/_functions.scss 185:10                                  luminance()
node_modules/@progress/kendo-theme-bootstrap/modules/@progress/kendo-theme-default/scss/core/functions/_colors.scss 416:12  contrast-wcag()
node_modules/@progress/kendo-theme-bootstrap/modules/@progress/kendo-theme-default/scss/button/_theme.scss 75:24            @content
node_modules/@progress/kendo-theme-bootstrap/modules/@progress/kendo-theme-default/scss/core/mixins/_import-once.scss 12:9  exports()
node_modules/@progress/kendo-theme-bootstrap/modules/@progress/kendo-theme-default/scss/button/_theme.scss 1:1              @import
node_modules/@progress/kendo-theme-bootstrap/scss/button/_theme.scss 1:9                                                    @import
node_modules/@progress/kendo-theme-bootstrap/scss/button/_index.scss 15:9                                                   @import
node_modules/@progress/kendo-theme-bootstrap/scss/toolbar/_index.scss 6:9                                                   @import
node_modules/@progress/kendo-theme-bootstrap/scss/adaptive/_index.scss 9:9                                                  @import
node_modules/@progress/kendo-theme-bootstrap/scss/grid/_index.scss 6:9                                                      @import
projects/lib/src/lib/app-theme/kendo.scss 38:9                                                                              @import
projects/admin/src/app/shared/layout/wrapper/wrapper.component.scss 6:9                                                     root stylesheet

✖ Failed to compile.

I know this is specific to kendo UI but is there any specific configuration we can do for fixing this issue?

Comment: What's @import projects/lib/src/lib/app-theme/kendo.scss look like?

Comment: Actually I have import kendo UI SCSS in this file like:
@import '../../../../../node_modules/@progress/kendo-theme-bootstrap/scss/popup/index';

Comment: I don't think the relative pathing is needed I have

@import '@progress/kendo-theme-material/scss/combobox';